# Clone (private) Github repo to EC2

Tags: github, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to clone a private Github repo to a new Amazon EC2 (Ubuntu) instance.

The EC2 Instance fails to `git clone <PATH>` due to

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Here's my steps:

1. Run `ssh-keygen` on local machine
2. Add the newly generated public key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) into GitHub 'SSH Keys' section
3. Also import that public key into the EC2 'Key Pairs' dashboard
4. Make the instance ensuring that new Key Pair is used during launch
5. log into EC2 instance, update `yum` and `yum install git` etc
6. Try `git clone <PATH>` but get permission error. Works fine on local machine...

I'm not fully understanding how EC2 is using my Key Pair... why doesn't GitHub recognize the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Also import that public key into the EC2 'Key Pairs' dashboard"

That only allows you to use that key pair for SSH into EC2 instances. And only instances that you create **after** you add that key pair to AWS. That key pair management dashboard has nothing to do with the `git` command you are running on the EC2 server.

You need to copy your local `~/.ssh/id_rsa` private key file to that same location on the EC2 server.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense regarding the KeyPair only working for SSH/login. I'm a bit of an SSH newbie though.. do I really copy the whole private key straight to the EC2 instance? Am I not supposed to keep private key secret from everyone including EC2?

Comment: "Am I not supposed to keep private key secret from everyone including EC2?" If you want to use the key in your Git commands, then you have to copy the key to the server where you are running the Git command. You could look into creating a GitHub deploy key that has limited access, and then copy that key into your EC2 instance, but at some point you have to copy some sort of private key onto the EC2 instance so it can actually authenticate with GitHub when you run Git commands.

Comment: using Deploy Keys also makes sense too - actually I was testing using AWS CloudFormation to send the EC2 "actual" public key to the Deploy Keys list of the repo (via GitHub restful API) b ut adding `ssh-keygen` to the CloudFormation instructions felt like bad form. Is running `ssh-keygen` on instance OK even though I gave it a Key Pair during spinup?

Comment: Yes running `ssh-keygen` just generates another key, separate from the key pair used for SSH access. Although I suggest storing the key somewhere like AWS SecretsManager and having the EC2 instance simply download it from there at startup. That way you can control access to the key via IAM permissions, and you don't need to add the key to GitHub each time you spin up a new EC2 instance.